# Oracle SQL Count Records per Hour

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

So, what I'm trying to do basically is count the amount of shipments, per hour, per carrier, but I'm having difficulties getting it to sum in the columns I want. The goal is to instead of having 1 or 2 under Hour 1 or Hour 2 it would have sum(total shipments). Essentially 24 hours so we could see trends in time of day...

Code:

```
    select router_destination_code, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then '1' else NULL end as "Hour 1",
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then '2' else NULL end as "Hour 2",
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then '3' else NULL end as "Hour 3",
--case when app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 16:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 17:00:00' then count(Router_Destination_code) else NULL end as "Hour_1"
count(Router_Destination_code) as Shipments
from booker.routing_container_history
where 
app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam')
and app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 16:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 16:00:00'
group by 
router_destination_code, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then '1' else NULL end, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then '2' else NULL end, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then '3' else NULL end
order by 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then '1' else NULL end, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then '2' else NULL end, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then '3' else NULL end, 
count(Router_Destination_code) desc;
```

Output:

[image]

But, the Goal is to have the shipments underneath the hour.

Thank you.

Here is a new approach I did.. But it is showing lots of zeros, and would like it only to show numbers the whole way across.

```
select router_destination_code, 
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '16' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 1",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '17' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 2"
--case when app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 16:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 17:00:00' then count(Router_Destination_code) else NULL end as "Hour_1"
--count(Router_Destination_code) as Shipments
from booker.routing_container_history
where 
app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam')
and app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 16:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 16:00:00'
group by 
router_destination_code, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '16' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '17' then router_destination_code else NULL end
order by 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '16' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '17' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
count(Router_Destination_code) desc;
```

Comment: The answer was found on this thread. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647329/oracle-sql-count-per-hour/20647392?noredirect=1#comment30911561_20647392

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understood you well but you may try to just extract hour from date and then group by:

Check this fiddle (sorry for bad syntax):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0a97/6

```
create table a (id number, data date);
insert into a (id, data)
values (1, to_date( '2013-01-01 13:12:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into a (id, data)
values (1, to_date( '2013-01-01 13:12:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into a (id, data)
values (1, to_date( '2013-01-01 14:12:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));

select to_char(data,'HH24'), count(1) from a group by to_char(data,'HH24');
```

Comment: Basically, where the column shipments is with the data, I would want that underneath Hour1, instead of in a seperate column, then same for each hour. Thanks.

Comment: Then the solution I proposed shall be OK. You will have something like this: Destination A | 01 | Shipments..... Destination A | 02 | Shipments.... and so on (to 24) then you can extract trends in an external app if you use any...

Comment: But, I am unable to create tables on my server as it is a RO.