# Oracle SQL count() per hour

Tags: sql, oracle, count, null, case

I have a query that shows the amount of shipments per hour, per carrier. I have it cased by hour, but it is showing zero's until the previous hour is complete before reporting data for next hour. Essentially, would like to read left to right, and have NULL if carrier didn't have shipment during that hour.

Code:

```
    select router_destination_code, 
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 1",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 2",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 3",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 4",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 5",
count(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then router_destination_code else NULL end) as "Hour 6"
from booker.routing_container_history
where 
app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam')
and app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 00:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 00:00:00'
group by 
router_destination_code, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then router_destination_code else NULL end
order by 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then router_destination_code else NULL end,
count(Router_Destination_code) desc;
```

Output:

[image]

**NEW QUERY FROM GORDON LINOFF**

```
select router_destination_code, 
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then 1 end) as "Hour 1",
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then 2 end) as "Hour 2",
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then 3 end) as "Hour 3",
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then 4 end) as "Hour 4",
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then 5 end) as "Hour 5",
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then 6 end) as "Hour 6"
from booker.routing_container_history
where 
app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam')
and app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 00:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 00:00:00'
group by 
router_destination_code, 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then 1 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then 2 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then 3 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then 4 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then 5 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then 6 end
order by 
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then 1 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then 2 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then 3 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then 4 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then 5 end,
case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then 6 end,
count(Router_Destination_code) desc;
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I replied to your answer below, everything seems to be working great! I responded below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `count(. . .)` use `sum(. . .)`, as in:

```
sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00'
         then 1 end) as "Hour 1"
```

EDIT:

Just to be clear, the query should be:

```
select router_destination_code, 
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then 1 end) as "Hour 1",
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then 1 end) as "Hour 2",
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then 1 end) as "Hour 3",
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then 1 end) as "Hour 4",
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then 1 end) as "Hour 5",
       sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then 1 end) as "Hour 6"
from booker.routing_container_history
where app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam') and
      app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 00:00:00' and 'dec/14/2013 00:00:00'
group by router_destination_code
order by sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '00' then 1 end),
         sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '01' then 1 end),
         sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '02' then 1 end),
         sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '03' then 1 end),
         sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '04' then 1 end),
         sum(case when to_char(app_last_updated_date_utc, 'HH24') = '05' then 1 end),
         count(Router_Destination_code) desc;
```

Comment: where you have then 1, wouldn't I want to then 'router_destination_code'? To do the sum? Basically I want the sum of router_destination_code when HH24 = 01, etc for 02,03 etc. Thanks.

Comment: I used your suggestions, But, now instead of 0 it says NULL..Updated question with new query.

Comment: will that be summing ALL within that timeframe, OR will it be averaging? Thanks.

Comment: @Spartacus38 . . . It will be summing all within the time frame, the same way that your original query counted all within the timeframe.

Comment: got it, it appears to work correctly. I think I may have just been surprised by the low numbers I was seeing.. haha, last thing, i'll mark your answer as correct. How do I have it say 0 instead of null? Thanks you da man

Comment: @Spartacus38 . . . You would add `else 0` to each of the `case` statements.